# PHP simple_html_dom -> wrap an element with a new anchor tag

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am using simple_html_dom manage the way CMS driven images are embed on a page. However I would like to be able to wrap any images that aren't already wrapped in anchor tags in a new anchor tag, but I can't work out how to wrap a simple_html_dom element with a new tag.

My code so far:

```
$content = str_get_html($content);
if(is_object($content))
{
    $elements = $content->find('img');
    foreach($elements as $element)
    {
/*
GET INFORMATION ABOUT WHAT IMAGE THIS IS - ALL FINE
*/          
$classStr = $element->class;
        if(trim(strlen($classStr)) > 0)
        {
            $needle = "wp-image-";
            $after = substr($classStr, strpos($classStr, $needle) + strlen($needle));
            if(strpos($after, " "))
            {
                $imageID = substr($after, 0, strpos($after, " "));
            }
            else
            {
                $imageID = $after;
            }   
/*
Get new image to link to
*/
$image = tona_get_image_by_id($imageID, "full");

/*
CHECK IF PARENT OF IMAGE IS AN ANCHOR... IF SO CHANGE THE LINK
*/

            $elementParent = $element->parent();
            if(isset($elementParent->href)) 
            {
                $elementParent->href = $image["src"];
                $elementParent->class .= " newAnchorClass ";    
            }
/*
IF NOT ADD A NEW ANCHOR TAG ** HELP **
*/

            echo "IMG: " . $imageID . " " . $image["src"] . "<br/>";    
            $element->href = $image["src"];
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what's the actual problem? What is wrong in/with your code?

Comment: Hi PLB - I can't figure out how to wrap my image (as contained in $element) with a new anchor. so that <img> becomes <a href=""><img></a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_access) under "Tips" tab:
    `$e->outertext = '<div class="wrap">' . $e->outertext . '<div>'`

If you want to further manipulate the element, you can use temporary variable to recreate the dom. In your case, it would be:

```
// '$element' is the element to be wrapped
$tempHtml = str_get_html('<a>' . $element->outertext . '</a>');
$link = $tempHtml->find('a', 0);
// '$src' is the url of the link
$link->href = $image['src'];
```